# Inline JS resulting in 2 new windows on mobile devices

Tags: javascript

The following code on an iPhone opens two new pages - Twitter and an empty page. What's wrong with this code? I'm returning a false from the local function so this behavior shouldn't occur.

```
<a href='http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=<?php echo $permalink; ?>' onclick='javascript:return (function(){window.open("http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=<?php echo $permalink; ?>", "MsgWindow", "width=600, height=600, scrollbars=yes", false); return false;})();'>
<img onmouseover="this.style.opacity='0.8'" onmouseout="this.style.opacity='1'" style="margin-right:5px; width:40px; height:40px" src="data:image/png;base64,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" alt="Twitter Share" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have an IIFE there. It should not be inline and the `javascript:` label is not needed

Here is a safer code - it alas does not run in a stacksnippet but you can copy it and use it in a page

Here is a working version

http://plungjan.name/SO/popup.html

```js
function clickOpen(e) {
  var w;
  try {
    w = window.open(this.href, this.target, "width=600,height=600,scrollbars");
  } catch (e) {
    return true; // let the link just work
  }
  return w ? false : true; // cancel click if window opened
}
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll("#social a")].forEach(lnk => lnk.addEventListener("click", clickOpen))
})
```

```html
<div id="social">
  <a href='http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=<?php echo $permalink; ?>' target="MsgWindow" class="popup">
    <img onmouseover="this.style.opacity='0.8'" onmouseout="this.style.opacity='1'" style="margin-right:5px; width:40px; height:40px" src="data:image/png;base64,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"
      alt="Twitter Share" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! May I ask? Why do I not want an IIFE?

Comment: Works great, but on mobile devices, I still get an extra empty page load for Twitter and Pinterest. But not for Facebook ... very strange.

Comment: New pages were opening b/c I was using http instead of https ... it works great now, thank you!

Comment: I do have one more question - the 600x600 param doesn't work. How do I fix this?

Comment: Ahh, I had a typo - missing hash in `querySelectorAll("#social a")` - http://plungjan.name/SO/popup.html works now

Answer (score 1):

I think you overcooking it with the self-executing function. You can simply add an additional return false as below. Keep it old school.

```
<a href='https://google.com' onClick='window.open("https://stackoverflow.com"); return false;'>
    Google, or so maybe not...
</a>
```

Ideally, you should not have this inline, but if you must then you can add additional functions separated by `;` and return false at the end.